# array difference

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have this array lets call it array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Machine] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [name] => XYZ
                    [priority] => 1
                )

            [Software] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 472
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Machine] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => ABC
                    [priority] => 0
                )

            [Software] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 470
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Machine] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => IEU
                    [priority] => 3
                )

            [Software] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 471
                )

        )

)
```

Then I have another array lets call it array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 6
)
```

If array 2 doesnt have  [Machine][id] then I want it to be removed from array 1. Like in above example 1 will removed

```
   [2] => Array
            (
                [Machine] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => IEU
                        [priority] => 3
                    )

                [Software] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 471
                    )

            )
```

any idea on how to achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like :

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array1 as $platform)
{
     if (in_array($platform["Machine"]["id"], $array2))
     {
         $new_array[] = $platform;
     }
}

return $new_array;
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps..

```
foreach ($array1 AS $key => $array) {
    if (!in_array($array['Machine']['id'], $array2))
       unset($array1[$key]);
}
```